# How do I control the header space in non-front pages in Twenty Seventeen?

Tags: theme-development, theme-twenty-seventeen

I'm not using the site title and tagline, so the headers in non-front pages are too thin to display the graphics I'm using.

I want to be able to control the height of the header in those other pages to display my graphics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can target several of the header elements using CSS. I'd use the site-branding like so:

```
.site-branding {
  min-height: 50vh;
}
```

This would set the minimum height of the element to 50% of the viewport height.

You can add this to your child theme's style.css or via the customizer if you're running a WordPress version greater than 4.7.

Comment: The customizer as in the category labeled "Additional CSS"?  I am running 4.7.4.

I threw the code in there, but it didn't change anything.